# How to prove that $a^b > b^a$ if $e \leq a <b$

Tags: real-analysis

It's a pretty simple question, but I haven't been able to figure it out. This was an assignment in a calculus course, so the method probably uses something with differentiation or integration, but beyond that I really haven't been able to make much headway on it.

Here's what I've tried so far:

Let $f(a) = a^b$ and $g(a) = b^a$. For $e \leq a < b$, if we assume $f(a)>g(a)$ to be true then it must also mean that $\ln(f(a)) > \ln(g(a))$.

Both $f(a)$ and $b(a)$ are monotonic and have a positive slope. Since both $a$ and $b$ are greater than $e$, then $\ln(f(a)) = b \ln a > 1$ and $\ln(f(b)) = a \ln b > 1$, and $b \ln a > a \ln b$.

Since both of these are positive (in fact larger than 1) and monotonically increase, then if $a<b$ the following must also be true:

$$\frac{d}{da} (b \ln a) > \frac{d}{da} (a \ln b) $$

This simplifies to

$$\frac{b}{a} > \ln b$$

Which is equivalent to

$$\frac{b}{\ln b} > a$$

However this can only be true if $1<b \leq e$, which contradicts our initial condition of $e \leq a < b$.

Any ideas on how to prove this inequality? Is my approach valid, or should I take a different approach?

Comment: Your assumption about the derivative inequality being true is false.

Comment: Actually that doesn't surprise me, I was mostly going off of intuition trying to find anything that might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost have it.  After getting to $$b ln(a) > a ln(b)$$ it might be easier to then conclude $$ b/ln(b) > a/ln(a) $$ and then prove that the function $x/ln(x)$ is monotonically increasing in the relevant interval.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. As long as $x>e$, then $x> \ln x$, and it's pretty simple to show that $x/ \ln x$ is monotonically increasing by showing that its derivative is always greater than 0.

Answer (score 2):

For $a,b>1,$
$$a^b>b^a\Leftrightarrow\frac{\ln a}a>\frac{\ln b}b.$$
This inequality holds if $e\le a<b$, since the function
$$f:x\mapsto\frac{\ln x}x$$
satifies
$$f'(x)=\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}$$
hence is decreasing on $[e,+\infty).$